# OWA cache site collection

Tags: cache, owa

I am provisioning few 2013 farm. Do I need to worry about  Office_Viewing_Service_Cache site collection? As I understand OWA requires separate non SP server like workflow.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete this Site Collection as it was only used for Office Web Apps 2010. Office Web Apps 2013/Office Online Server do not use a Site Collection for caching purposes.